# retrieving elements from data returned as json from django view

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, django

In my `django` view ,I am using `simplejson` to convert some search results to `json`

```
vals = [('supposed to be a toaster.', 8),('we can do more than one thing.',14),("we could make a bicycle.",51)]

result={'results':vals}

serialized = simplejson.dumps(result)
```

serialized=>

```
{"msg": "success!.",  "results": [["supposed to be a toaster.", 8], ["we can do more than one thing.", 14], [" we could make a bicycle.", 51]]}
```

I can send this serialized data to javascript function by

```
return HttpResponse(serialized, mimetype="application/json")
```

In my javascript function(using jquery),I can retrieve the data as

```
var data = $.parseJSON(res.responseText);
var results = data['results']
```

I would like to show the results in the following format

```
8  -- supposed to be a toaster. 
14 -- we can do more than one thing
51 -- we could make a bicycle
```

How can I do this in javascript?   The javascript variable `results` contain s

```
supposed to be a toaster.,8,we can do more than one thing.,14,we could make a bicycle.,51,
```

Will I have to use `regex` to separate the items?or is there a better solution? What makes use of regex difficult is that,the 
strings may sometimes contain numbers .

**Edit**

Thanks to the replies by Priyank and alexey28 ,I tried

```
for(var item in results) {
    var time = results[item][1];
    console.log('time='+time);
    var resStr =results[item][0];
    console.log('resStr='+resStr);
    formatedResult += time+ " --- " + resStr+'<br>';
}
$('#showresults').html(formatedResult);
```

Comment: i think you can iterate over data['results'] by using simple javascript for loop. console "data" .. and see in firebug wht u see ...

Comment: thanks Priyank, that would work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Variable data will contains array, so you can:

```
var formatedResult = "";
for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var item = data[i];
    formatedResult += item[1] + " --- " + item[0];
}
// Set html for you <div id="resultOutput"></div>:
jQuery("div#resultOutput").html(formatedResult);
```

Comment: hi,I modified your solution a bit and got it working..please see my edited question